# Topos-theoretic Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory, topos-theory, fundamental-group

[This page](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Galois+theory) is an overview of some of the types of "Galois theories" there are. One of the most basic type is the [fundamental theorem of covering spaces](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/fundamental+theorem+of+covering+spaces), which says, roughly, that for each topological space $X$, there is an equivalence of categories
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X)\simeq \pi_1(X)\mathbf{Set}.$$
Grothendieck proved an analogue of that statement for schemes $X$:
$$\mathrm{EtCov}(X)\simeq \pi_1(X)\mathbf{Set}.$$
(This is again just a very rough formulation and omits some of the assumptions, but you know what I mean.)

I am interested in ["topos-theoretic Galois theory"](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Galois+theory#topostheoretic_galois_theory). Unfortunately, this section of the nLab page isn't filled out ("(...)"), but I *guess* that the topos-theoretic formulation of Galois theory states, roughly, that for each *topos* $\mathcal E$,
$$\mathrm{Gal}(\mathcal E)\simeq \pi_1(\mathcal E)\mathbf{Set},\qquad (\ast)$$
where $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathcal E)$ is the full subcategory of $\mathcal E$ consisting of locally constant objects in $\mathcal E$, and $\pi_1(\mathcal E)$ is the fundamental group of $\mathcal E$. (This is suggested by the nLab section "Reformulation of classical Galois theory".)

**Question:** *Is there a reference for $(\ast)$ (and the definition of the fundamental group of a topos which is used here)? Is this in SGA 4?*

The linked nLab page [fundamental group of a topos](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/fundamental+group+of+a+topos) refers to (and is mostly copy-pasted from) Porter's paper [Abstract Homotopy Theory: The interaction of category theory and homotopy theory](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/files/Abstract-Homotopy.pdf), which contains a section called "The fundamental group of a topos", which in turn refers to SGA 1. This is weird, because SGA 1 doesn't discuss topoi, so in particular not the fundamental group of a topos!

The nLab also refers to SGA 4 Exposé IV Exercice 2.7.5 for the definition of the fundamental group and SGA 4 Exposé VIII Proposition 2.1 for, I guess, $(\ast)$ in the special case that $\mathcal E$ is the étale topos of the scheme $X=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ for some field $k$. (But this is really just a guess - I can't read French. So correct me if I'm wrong.) Is there more of "topos-theoretic Galois theory" in SGA 4 or are these the only two paragraphs about that topic?

Concerning the definition of the fundamental group of a topos, there is a construction in Moerdijk's *Classifying Spaces and Classifying Topoi*, in which he nevertheless remarks:

> The *profinite* fundamental group is discussed in
> SGA1.

This suggests there are two version of the fundamental group of a topos: the one he discusses and the "profinite" version. However, as I said, topoi don't occur in SGA 1, so I wonder where I can find the definition of the "profinite" fundamental group, if that's the notion that should be used in $(\ast)$. (The definition used in $(\ast)$ should of course have the property that if $\mathcal E$ is the étale topos of a scheme $X$, then $\pi_1(\mathcal E)$ is isomorphic to the étale fundamental group of $X$.)

Comment: Have you checked 8.4 of Johnstone's (first, 1977) topos theory book?

Comment: Grothendieck's Galois theory is limited to finite covering spaces i.e. locally constant sheaves of finite sets. I don't know for which topoi the category of locally constant sheaves of finite sets is a Galois category in Grothendieck's sense. More generally, there is a notion of a (tame) infinite Galois category due to Bhatt and Scholze. I think they show an example of a topos such that locally constant sheaves do not form a tame infinite Galois category. I am sure you can always define the "shape" of a topos as a pro-homotopy type, but I don't know how its $\pi_1$ relates to local systems.

Comment: Let me start by a disclaimer, I am no expert in the subject discussed nor am I working in the field, just a curious fellow who was intrigued by those beautiful concepts once and remember a couple of references. Borceux and Janelidze's book "Galois Theories", might be a good place to look. I also remember Olivia Caramello (perhaps with Laurent Lafforgue) did some work in the subject, a simple google search should give you something. There is also an old paper of Barr and Diaconescu "On locally simply  connected toposes and their fundamental groups".

Comment: Ah, using Google translator I think Exercice 2.7.5 is exactly the statement $(\ast)$.

Comment: I first learned of fundamental groups of topoi from http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CTGDC_1981__22_3_301_0

Comment: @Andry Thanks for the references!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Is that the fundamental group that is used in $(\ast)$? Moerdijk's comment suggests there are several variants of "fundamental group of a topos".

Comment: The (pro)finite version, to be precise. And I now recalled, more general version can be also found in "[On the representation theory of Galois and Atomic Topoi](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208222)" by Dubuc

Comment: Does Dubuc prove $(\ast)$?

Comment: He has prodiscrete version, see Theorem 3.4.1 (page 26)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Very nice, thanks! :-)

Comment: You might also find useful "[What is the fundamental group?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404989901345)" by J. F. Kennison. In that paper, for a connected locally connected locale $X$, to each connected base $\mathcal V$ of $X$ a sheaf of groups $\pi_{\mathscr V}$ on $X$ is assigned such that, given a point $x:1\to X$, the inverse limit over all $\mathscr V$ of groups $x^*\pi_{\mathscr V}$ gives the fundamental progroup of $X$. In nice cases it agrees with the "usual" fundamental group.

Comment: Still another approach by the late Dito Pataraia mighr also interest you. In "[Internal categories in a left exact cosimplicial category](https://www.emis.de/journals/GMJ/vol4/v4n6-4.pdf)" he considers, for a topos $X$, toposophic groupoids $G$ together with a morphism of simplicial toposes $N(G)\to ad(X)$ where $N(G)$ is the nerve of $G$ and $ad(X)$ is the antidiscrete simplicial topos (with the topos of $n$-simplices equal to $X^{n+1}$), such that constituting geometric morphisms $N(G)_n\to X^{n+1}$ are local homeomorphisms. These, with obvious morphisms, form a category $S(X)$.

Comment: Since in particular $G_0\to X$ is a local homeomorphism, there is a forgetful functor $U:S(X)\to X$. Dito considers the case when $X$ *admits the notion of a discrete category* - by definition this means that $U$ has a left adjoint right inverse $F$. Then $F(1)$ has all good properties of the universal cover for $X$, and in good cases agrees with it. In particular, for a point $x:1\to X$ one obtains a toposophic groupoid $x^*F(1)$ which again in nice enough cases turns out to be a discrete groupoid with unique object and automorphism group equal to the fundamental group of $X$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for your comments! :-)

Answer (score 7):

I believe that chapter $5$ of [Galois Theories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/galois-theories/8D017BD1A8DFB0F0EBD01DCDAA134FEE) by Borceux and Janelidze contains what you're looking for -- they develop a general 'categorical Galois theorem' invoking toposes.

Chapter 7 gets even more general, presenting a 'non-Galoisian Galois theorem' that holds for any descent morphism in a category -- a morphism $f$ is a descent morphism iff the 'pullback along $f$' functor is monadic.

There is also the classic paper by Joyal and Tierney, [An Extension of the Galois theory of Grothendieck](http://www.ams.org/books/memo/0309/), where they prove that each Grothendieck topos is equivalent to the category of equivariant sheaves on a groupoid internal to the category of locales.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.10941.pdf) by Christopher Townsend might be of interest to your specific question; he re-proves Joyal and Tierney’s result on the representation of Grothendieck toposes as localic groupoids using a simplified case of the aforementioned categorical Galois theorem, then proceeds to actually prove the whole theorem using this trivial case as a key ingredient.

Comment: I don't think this is in Chapter 5 of the book by Borceux et al, because topoi are defined later in chapter 7. There they discuss the Joyal-Tierney result. Does the Joyal-Tierney result imply $(\ast)$?

Comment: Also, I don't see how the Townsend paper is related to my specific question.

Comment: I have the feeling Joyal-Tierney and $(\ast)$ are somewhat different generalizations of the fundamental theorem of covering spaces.

Comment: @user1022117 I'll have to think on wether $(*)$ is a special case of the Joyal-Tierney result or not, but I'm curious about why you're convinced that $(*)$ is the 'correct' generalization?

Comment: I didn't claim it's the "correct" one. I'm just asking about it.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you would like to see the thesis of O. Leroy, **Groupoïde fondamental et théorème de Van Kampen en théorie des topos**, available from https://plmbox.math.cnrs.fr/f/7ffa366379144dd4bacc/?dl=1 — the password is : groupoide

(a project of [transcription](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/leroy.pdf))

---

or the thesis of V. Zoonekynd, **La Tour de Teichmuller-Grothendieck**, available from https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00001140/document

Comment: A very clear summary for some of the ideas in Leroy's thesis is in this paper by Zoonekynd: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111071 (Section 1).

Comment: Which theorem is it in these documents?

Comment: Without a specific reference to a theorem that doesn't at all answer my **Question**.